# How read data from file gulp.src('json/username.json') in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, gulp

How read data file from `gulp.src('json/username.json')` in **node_modules** (*node_modules / gulp-up / index.js*)?

**username.json**

---

```
{
  "name": "Rikardo",
  "city": "Mosscov",
  "age": "18"
}
```

---

**gulpfile.js**

```
upmodul = require("gulp-up");

gulp.task('gulp-ren', function () {
    return gulp.src('json/username.json')
       .pipe(myfunction());
});

gulp.task('ge', ['gulp-ren']);
```

---

**node_modules / gulp-up / index.js**

```
'use strict';
var Stream = require('stream');


function loger() {
    //The needed maybe not Transform and Read file
    var stream = new Stream.Transform({ objectMode: true });


    stream._transform = function (file, unused, callback) {
        console.log('test !!!  - ' + file.contents);

        return stream;
    }
}

module.exports =  loger;
```

I write in console command: `gulp ge`  , and give error:

---

```
    [00:19:39] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer
    -WebProg\domains\progectapi2\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\
    lib\_stream_readable.js:516:7)
        at Gulp.<anonymous> (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\domains\p
    rogectapi2\gulpfile.js:159:9)
        at module.exports (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\domains\pro
    gectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg
    \domains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg
    \domains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (E:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\do
    mains\progectapi2\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
        at C:\Users\Tiki
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:433:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:362:13)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:432:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question... but if you want to read the `json/username.json` file, then you can just require it, like so:

```
var json = require('json/username.json');
```

The json variable will contain the data from the username.json file.

Comment: Tanks . I want of .pipe(myfunction());  read - json/username.json of Stream = require('stream');   I will edit my question and add many information.